# Show TextView when pulling down a ListView

Tags: android

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to show a TextView that would be on top of a ListView but not shown, when I pull down the ListView the TextView reveals itself, if I let go the TextView hides again. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Like a "Pull To Refresh" TextView?

Comment: @iturki Something like that but I was wondering if there was a solution to this that doesn't need a custom View.

Comment: I'm afraid not. You either use an existing custom View or you build yours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can achieve that is by using a Custom View or by building yours. ListView doesn't support this feature.

If you consider using a Custom View then you should check out this [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) widget. It:

- Supports ListView, ExpandableListView GridView & WebView!
- Used by great apps like: Friendcaster, TweetCaster, Plume &The Verge.
- Supports Pulling-down and Pulling-up.
- Very customizable.